When using Micrometer in SpringBoot, how to propagate traceId and spainId onto a file uploaded to AWS S3?
Is it possible to propagate the tracing info to a file uploaded to AWS S3, or to an SFTP?
This way, if somebody is polling from a directory, I want for him to be able to continue using the same traceId the file has in the metadata, on the fly, so the logs can be correlated in Kibana. I want to fully trace the whole flow between microservices that use AWS S3 and custom polling strategy as a communication solution.
In the AWS S3 documentation is stated that you can add custom metadata information using the prefix x-amz-meta-, but I am not sure if the polling should then gather that trace and force it onto the Tracer bean, overriding the default one.
Furthermore, for writing we use AWS S3, but for reading we use plain SFTP, so I don't know if those metadata values stored in S3 are going to be respected by the SFTP poller on read. Maybe I need to integrate this manually?
Thanks in advance.

Yes, AWS S3 allows you to add custom metadata to files using the prefix x-amz-meta-. This metadata is ideal for storing tracing information like traceId. For example:
aws s3 cp your-file.txt s3://your-bucket/your-file.txt \
    --metadata x-amz-meta-traceid=your-trace-id

But, when polling files via SFTP, this metadata is not automatically preserved. SFTP only exposes the file content, size, permissions, etc., not custom S3 metadata. That's why you need a manual integration to propagate tracing information when working with SFTP.

But if I cannot gather the S3 metadata from the SFTP file when polling, how can I get its traceId to integrate it manually?

you need to propagate the traceId by embedding it into the file name or the file content during the upload process. This ensures the traceId is accessible downstream when polling the file via SFTP.
